# Android GcmListenerService onMessageReceived() methoad not called

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

GcmListenerService  onMessageReceived() method not called when the application is closed in few devices for an example OPPO A83. Can you please help to fix it ?

Comment: gcm is deprecated, use fcm

Comment: Is it not possible to fix with GcmListenerService?

Comment: the drawback of gcm was the same that you are experiencing. It doesn't used to work on all devices

Comment: @VivekMishra thank you.